# jquery validate plugin Using dependency and set arguments

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

My question is quite simple :

How to set dependency on a field and set params to the rule function ?
What's the key to set params in ?

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        somefield: {
            minlength: {
                depends: function() {
                    return $('#checkbox').prop('checked');
                }, 
                keyToSetParams??: 5
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Without dependency, it would look like this :

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        somefield: {
            minlength: 5
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution after some debugging, the key name is "param" so it look like:

```
$('#form').validate({
    rules: {
        somefield: {
            minlength: {
                depends: function() {
                    return $('#checkbox').prop('checked');
                }, 
               param: 5
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought this wasn't possible.. didn't work when i tried. I must have done something wrong :)